# Warning message in existing project after upgrade to Xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode

I have just recently upgraded to Xcode 7 and now I get this warning:
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

I researched different forums and everybody with similar issue recommends to remove paths from build settings but I can't find any paths there resembling iPhone simulators....

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, here are the steps that worked for me

1. open your project
2. got to TARGETS
3. select youAppNameTests
4. select Build Settings
5. Framework Search Paths
6. Delete every thing from Debug and Release fields
7. clean project

Hope it will work for you too

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the test target. Delete your test target. (Copy the code out to some other program if there is any.) Quit Xcode and [clean out the Derived Data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073). Now open your project again, and the problem will be gone. If necessary, now make a new test target.